# JQuery Autocomplete asp.net Webservice returning key/value pair

Tags: jquery, web-services, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

I have been using this example

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-jQuery-AutoComplete-Plugin-in-ASP.Net.aspx

in order to return data from webservice back to jquery autocomplete. Now I am trying to find out is there a way to return key/value pair from WebService, instead of returning just a single string with

```
context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```